# How replace flatpickr to angular material design datepicker

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-material, angular5

I have problem with replacing flatpickr (jQuery) datepicker to angular material design date picker. In project is create grid file (.ts), which return html.

```
 return `<input id="${this.configurationObject.tableName}_${colIndex}" class="form-control fp-date ${this.customSearchClass}"
         data-column-index="${colIndex}" data-column-type-input="false" value="${val}"
          type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" ${readonly ? 'readonly="readonly"' : ''}/>`;
```

I need replace it with angular material design. And when I click on input, calendar should be automatically open.
I tried:

```
return ` <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateDatepicker"  placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
                 name="targetApprovalDate" class="form-control table-col-search" (click)="dateDatepicker.open()">
          <mat-datepicker #dateDatepicker></mat-datepicker>`;
```

But when i click on input, calender not open.
Thank you

Comment: Any error in the console

Comment: @PardeepJain, Any error in console. The click event is not recognized

Comment: is `dateDatepicker.open()` is valid method?

Comment: @PardeepJain, yes it is. There is demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: in stackblitz its working fine, can you cross check

Comment: yes, it is working. It is normal angular ang material design. But I need return this how html, which I append to another html